# Get QPixmap dynamic image path from std::string

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

I have a problem with the `QPixmap` under Qt. I want to set the Pixmap Image Path dynamically from a `std::string`. I have tried some variations, but without success.

This is my code:

```
QPixmap pixmap("data/25eaad8879f1d018caec98546279804f.png"); // this is working
// label

ui->imageSite1->setPixmap(pixmap); //working
```

But if I try to set the `pixmappath` dynamically, I don't see the image (inside the label).
e.g.

```
string path = "data/"+imgname+".png"; // imgname is a dynamic parameter

QPixmap pixmap(path); // this is not working

// label
ui->imageSite1->setPixmap(pixmap);
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Documentation of QPixmap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html), you'll see the `load` method declared as taking a `QString` as parameter. So you either have to build a QString directly (judging by your example, I think this is the better way) or convert the `std::string` to a `QString` with a constructor of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I have to load the filepath from a textfile and at the end of the line was a `\n`. They can't load the image in this case.

I removed this and load the pixmap via the `load` method. Now it's working.

```
string path = "data/"+imgfilepath;
QString testPath = QString::fromStdString(path);
qDebug() << testPath;
QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap.load(testPath);
```